# Postgresql Index scan performed with LIKE query even though no varchar_pattern_ops is defined and not using "C" Locale

Tags: postgresql, indexing

Given the following table:

```
CREATE UNLOGGED TABLE table (
  col1       VARCHAR(64)   NOT NULL,
  col2       VARCHAR(255)      NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT table_pk PRIMARY KEY (col1,col2)
);
```

And following `SHOW LC_COLLATE;` result:

| lc_collate |
| --- |
| en_US.utf8 |

The following query performs an indexed scan:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE col1 ='val1' AND col2 LIKE ('prefix%') LIMIT 2;
```

As can be seen by its `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` output:

```
Limit  (cost=0.14..8.16 rows=1 width=662) (actual time=0.018..0.022 rows=0 loops=1)
  ->  Index Only Scan using table_pk on "table"  (cost=0.14..8.16 rows=1 width=662) (actual time=0.008..0.012 rows=0 loops=1)
        Index Cond: (col1 = 'val1'::text)
        Filter: ((col2)::text ~~ 'prefix%'::text)
        Heap Fetches: 0
Planning time: 4.562 ms
Execution time: 0.068 ms
```

The question is how does this query which contains `LIKE` operator performs an indexed scan?

By [this article](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/indexes-opclass.html) as well as [this blog](https://blog.cleverelephant.ca/2016/08/pgsql-text-pattern-ops.html) the case when using `LIKE` operator without "C" locale and without `varchar_pattern_ops` set on the index, should not be able to perform an indexed scan.

I am running this on a docker image of `postgres:9.6`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look closely, you will see that only `col1` is used as an “index condition”, that is, the index is not scanned for the condition on `col2`. The condition on `col2` is in the “filter”.

So everything is just as you expect it to be. The sequence of events during this index scan is like this:

1. fetch the next index entry that has `col1 = 'val1'`
2. fetch the table row for that entry
3. check if the table row is visible and satisfies `col2 LIKE 'prefix%'`; if yes, return that row
4. continue scanning the index in step 1. until we are done

To help you with the underlying problem: It would be nice if you coud define the primary key using a non-standard operator class, so that the primary key index supports your query perfectly, but that is not possible. These are your options:

- Drop the primary key and define a unique index with `text_pattern_ops` instead.  If both columns are `NOT NULL`, that is just as good.
- Create a `text_pattern_ops` index on `col2` alone. That can be used by itself or in combination with the primary key index.
- Create a second index on both columns.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! So if I understand correctly, in order for both columns to be indexed scanned and not just col1, I do need to use `varchar_pattern_ops` or `text_pattern_ops` on the primary key?

Comment: You would, but you cannot use a non-standard operator class with a primary key index. Either create a second index (not appealing) or do without a primary key and define a unique index on non-null columns (which is just as good as a primary key and the best solution).

Comment: Let's say I went for this solution `CREATE INDEX col2_idx ON table (col2 VARCHAR_PATTERN_OPS);` . How should my `explain analyze` look now? Because I can still see the "filter".

Comment: That's because the second condition is not selective enough to warrant a second index scan. The plan in your question has no "rows removed by filter".

Comment: Was it because I didn't have any data in the table? I inserted some now and I see even though I added the index above, the  query performs a seq scan: 
`Limit  (cost=0.00..0.05 rows=2 width=38) (actual time=0.285..0.306 rows=2 loops=1)
  ->  Seq Scan on "table"  (cost=0.00..2334.01 rows=99991 width=38) (actual time=0.275..0.284 rows=2 loops=1)
        Filter: (((col2)::text ~~ 'job_name_prefix%'::text) AND ((col1)::text = 'SOME_CAT'::text))
Planning time: 0.999 ms
Execution time: 0.354 ms`

Comment: OK that was because all my data was identical on col2? Added a few different rows and now it's back to this one: `Limit  (cost=0.42..2.02 rows=2 width=38) (actual time=0.029..0.052 rows=2 loops=1)
  ->  Index Scan using primary_idx on "table"  (cost=0.42..8.44 rows=10 width=38) (actual time=0.020..0.030 rows=2 loops=1)
        Index Cond: (((col2)::text ~>=~ 'other'::text) AND ((col2)::text ~<~ 'othes'::text))
        Filter: (((col2)::text ~~ 'other_prefix%'::text) AND ((col1)::text = 'SOME_CAT'::text))
Planning time: 0.906 ms
Execution time: 0.104 ms`. This time definitely removed rows

Comment: This time it used the other index. But this seems to be drifting away from the original question. I cannot give you a tutorial about how indexes work in PostgreSQL in general.

Comment: I agree. I am just trying to apply the answer you've given me and measure whether it accomplished what you intended. Since I cannot drop the PK I adopted the other (not appealing) answer.